# change orientation without onCreate call

Tags: android

i want to change layout without calling the onCreate method. i also define android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in my activity and it is not calling the onCreate method but the layout not adjust appropriately on landscape mode.

my current layout look like as follows.

[image]

after change orientation as landscape it look like as follows:
[image]

but on landscape i want the following result.

[image]

is there any auto adjacent property?

how can i do it?

Comment: Do you want to have your application in landscape mode per default or what exactly are you trying?

Answer (score 4):

there is no auto adjust property while view changes from portrait to landscape.

For images that you want to display in landscape mode

Create one filename.xml file and design your layout for landscape mode. 
Give filename same as your previous xml file in layout folder that you are using for activity.

Create folder in res/ name as layout-land and then keep that filename.xml file in res/layout-land folder

It will automatically call that res/layout-land/filename.xml when orientation changes from portrait to landscape.

Or you can also use

```
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {

      super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

      if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
          //your code
      } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
         //your code
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

See this documentation th handle this

http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/faster-screen-orientation-change.html

Comment: **This is a design error.** It is chosen based on **convenience** for the android team http://goo.gl/zoCJV. The blame is on the android team. I'm disgusted by the tone used in the documentation which suggests that it is not their fault.

Answer (score 1):

You could add `android:configChanges="orientation"` to Activity tag on AndroidManifest.xml.
Try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you're using a LinearLayout, because you didn't specify, but there's a function in the LinearLayout class called setOrientation() that should fix this.  You'll have to create an instance of your layout in your java file (which you may have already done) and then create either an orientationchange or resize event listener on your window.  After that it's just changing the orientation to horizontal/vertical based on screen orientation.

Comment: i am using TableLayout. is this possible in linear layout.

Comment: if it is possible through LinearLayout, please provide me sample code.

Comment: yeah, it's way easy to use LinearLayout, you can find source code anywhere

Answer (score 0):

You only put this  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" in your activity tag in android manifest.it works.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your manifest bro..

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|uiMode"
```

It's solve your and my problem :D